# How to properly redirect in NodeJS/ExpressJS?

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, redirect

I am building a shopping cart application in nodejs/expressjs. I am having some issues with redirecting to the correct page after a user has signed in. I have found several articles that relate closely but all of my attempts to fix it from those given articles is not doing the trick.

```
    access: function(req, res){
  var data = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
  console.log(data);
      Customers.findOne({"custEmail": data.custEmail}, function(err, user){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
          res.send("error");
        }if(!user){
          console.log("user not found");
          res.send("error");
        }else{
          console.log("user found");
          bcrypt.compare(data.custPassword, user.custPassword, function(err, reponse){
            if(reponse){
              req.session.regenerate(function(err){
                if(err){
                  console.log(err);
                  res.send("error");
                }else{
                  req.session.success = true;
                  res.send("Success");
                  //res.redirect('/');
                }
              });
            }else{
              console.log("error");
            }
          });
          }
      });
```

What happens is, a user enters their login information and clicks the login button. An Ajax request sends the data to this access function. The function starts by checking to see if the user exists in the database. If it does than it continues to compare the bcrypt password, if they are equal they successfully login and if they do not equal then obviously it errors out.

The issue seems to be here: `}else{
                  req.session.success = true;
                  res.send("Success");
                  //res.redirect('/');
                }`

When the user email and the password match this is hit right here. It says.. set this session to true, so the user can access pages where this session is required, and then sends a Success message back to the ajax request. This currently works perfectly fine and the res.send is sent to the front end. When I uncomment the res.redirect, the expected result of 'cannot set headers after they are set' happens. So when I comment out the res.send, the res.redirect simply ends up not working at all. No error, no breaking of anything just simply nothing.

I am curious to why this redirect here would not work? The headers are not being set anywhere else in this function and the expected result should be that the redirect would work perfectly fine. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you send an ajax call with either `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch()` and get the response, the browser does not do anything to the current page in the browser based on that response.  So, it doesn't matter whether you send a redirect response to the ajax call or not.  The browser won't change the current page in the browser, no matter what.  Ajax responses generate data for your Javascript and your Javascript must then decide what to do with it.

**FYI, the browser will change the current page only when the redirect happens from a browser page request or a browser submitted form post (not Javascript submitted).**  Since that is not how you are logging in, you can't use a redirect to change the current browser page.

So, if you're going to use an ajax call on the client for login and you want the client to change pages after a successful Ajax login, then you probably want to send the redirect URL in the login response and have the client process it and set `window.location` to do the redirect on login.

For example, you could change:

```
res.send("Success");
```

to this:

```
res.json({status: "Success", redirect: '/'});
```

And, then have your client code examine the return from the ajax call and if the status is successful, it can grab the redirect property and do something like:

```
if (ajaxResult.status === "Success") {
    window.location = ajaxResult.redirect;
}
```

> I am curious to why this redirect here would not work? The headers are
> not being set anywhere else in this function and the expected result
> should be that the redirect would work perfectly fine. Any help is
> greatly appreciated.

The message about headers have already been sent means that the whole response has already been sent with `res.send("Success");` and you are now trying to send another response.  You only get one response for a given request.  Once you've done `res.send("Success");`, the http server object has sent the whole response and then closed off that response.  You can't send more data at that point.

Comment: HEY THANK YOU. Your first initial resposne was enough for me. I ended up just removing the Ajax request because it was not 100% necessary. I just like the way Ajax works so figured I would use it here. Instead I took out the Ajax and just grabbed the req.body.data from the page on the submit of the form.. Then it was as easy as placing the correct redirect there. Appreciate your timely and extremely helpful answer!

Comment: I dont want to change or delete anything from your response.. if you want to bold this statement: Redirects do not generally apply to ajax calls because the browser doesn't process them on an ajax call (the browser processes redirects on a page load or a form post response). in your response that would be excellent. This sentence in itself helped me decide to just not use Ajax in this specific case.

Comment: Will you take a look at this post as well please? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089118/how-to-make-a-successful-ajax-request-using-javascript-on-page-load)

Answer (score 0):

I ask a question a question somewhere else, and stackoverflow leads me here.

### Why can't `res.redirect()` after `res.render()`

Just for people bump into same question as mine, I made a summary here.
After `res.render()`, the response ends. And `res.redirect()` will set the Header to the new url in Location, which we have already sent to client, and can't be set again.

My solution for this is to code in the client side `location.href ="/"`, if that page receive a variable like `redirectAttribute = true` in html tag.