# Nodejs express redirecting users to the home page on error 404

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

[Update] the issue was resolved. The code below is the working version.

I was trying to redirect the user back to the home page in case they typed the wrong URL. Inside the express code, I have created a function that saves user temporary data in the localhost:8000/users folder.

```
My file structure is:
Data/data.html (added on [Update] for temporarily storing the data) 
node_modules
static
static/index.html
static/JS/script.js
app.js
package-lock.json
package.json
```

Here's the index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sending data to and from the server</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h4 id="log1"></h4>
    </div>
    <input id="grab1" type="text">
    <input id="press1" type="button" value="Send">
    <input id="show1" type="button" value="Show">
    <div id="output1"></div>
    <script src="./JS/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Ajax fuction for sending data
    function send(data) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8000",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "string",
            data: data
        })
    }

    //Sending Data to the server
    $("#press1").on("click", () => {
        send({
            data: $("#grab1").val()
        })
        $("#log1").html("Successfully sent")
    });

    //Showing Output received from the server
    $("#show1").on("click", () => {
        $.get("/users", (data) => {
            $("#output1").html(`<h3>${ data }</h3>`);
        });
    });
});
```

[Update] this is the working version of the server side app.js script.

```
    // Importing Modules
const express = require("express")
const path = require("path")
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const fs = require("fs")

// Using bodyParser and setting localhost directory to static
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
app.use('/users', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Data', "data.html")));



// Post1 listens to all incoming posts 
function Post1() {
    app.post("/*", (postRequest, postResponse) => {
        // if it's localhost:8000 than then following function will run for 
        // the post and so on for each url.
        if (postRequest.headers.referer == "http://localhost:8000/") {
            // bigP1 is the string received from the ajax function
            bigP1 = postRequest.body.data;
            fs.writeFile("./Data/data.html", `${ bigP1 }`, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("done");
                }
            })
        }
        // It's the same function for else (at least for now)
        else if (postRequest.headers.referer == "http://localhost:8000/index.html") {
            bigP1 = postRequest.body.data;
            fs.writeFile("./Data/data.html", `${ bigP1 }`, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("done");
                }
            })
        }
        // If the post path is unidentified than the following is 
        // sent.    
        else {
            res.send(`<h1>${req.params.name} is not a website</h1>\n<a href="http://localhost:8000/">Go back</a>`)
        }
    })
}
// running Post1 here
Post1()


app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
    res.send(`<h1>${ req.params.name } is not a website</h1>\n<a href="http://localhost:8000/">Go back</a>`);
})

app.listen(8000)
```

Thank you for viewing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it could be happening two things.

- If you want to also allow *localhost:8000/* as a valid path for the *header.referrer* you could do something like

```
    if (postRequest.headers.referer == "http://localhost:8000/" ||
        postRequest.headers.referer == "localhost:8000/" ) {
         ...
        }
```

- But if the problem is in the redirection itself, maybe the problem is that you are trying to redirect someone using AJAX and it wont happen with that kind of method.

In that case you could include an object in your response that contains something like

```
{status : "succes", redirect: ""} or {status: "fail", redirect: "http://localhost:8000}"
```

Then you could have a function in yout script that searchs for the status and when it finds a *"fail"* runs

```
window.location = redirect;
```

**If you are intrested in expand this kind of solution, you could check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41078774/11280510**

On the other hand, if you are trying to avoid something the case that someone could retrive information making a request outside your web, you could play around with the **content-policy-header**.

**For more information about it: https://content-security-policy.com/**

Comment: Ok, it's working now. And I've also decided to use the file system module to be able to overwrite the file every time the user runs a function. Thank you for the tip.