# Express response methods don't work after verifying ID token from Firebase through a middleware

Tags: node.js, express, firebase-admin

I am trying to build a web application using Firebase and NodeJS with ejs templates at the client. I want to make sure the user is authenticated before accessing a particular route through a middleware. In this middleware, I verify ID tokens sent through the client and then render the page if they are verified. But when the tokens are verified the app doesn't show the new page i.e. "user-profile.ejs".

```html
<button onclick="sendRequest('/profile')">Profile</button>
```

```js
//The client function which sends ID token 
function sendRequest(url){
  if(firebase.auth().currentUser){
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
    .then(idToken => {
      client({
        method: 'get',
        url: url,
        headers: {
          'authtoken': idToken
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
          console.log("Auth token sent.")      
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
    }else{
      client({
        method: 'get',
        url: url,
      }).then(res => {
         console.log("Request sent without header.")
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
   }
}
```

```js
//The NodeJS server which contains the routes and checkAuth middleware

function checkAuth(req,res,next){
  if(req.headers.authtoken){
    console.log('Auth token with headers received. User has logged in.')
    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.headers.authtoken)
    .then(verifiedUser => {
      console.log('Auth token verified')
      return next()
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      res.redirect('back')
    })
  }else{
    console.log('Without header received.')
    res.redirect('back')
  }
}

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('home')
})


app.get('/profile',checkAuth,(req,res)=>{
  console.log("Reached user profile")
  res.send("user-profile")
})
```

Comment: In the link of your page, you have this code `sendRequest('/profile')`.  The only result that has in the code for `sendRequest()` is some `console.log()` statements.  Ajax calls do not automatically modify the current page in the browser in any way by themselves.  So, if your server does a redirect or sends a response, all that does is return that status or that content to your ajax code.  If you want to actually redirect the browser or do something with the response, your Javascript that sends the ajax call has to look at the response and cause some change itself,

Comment: For example, if you want the browser to redirect, you'd have to examine the response status, see it was a 3xx http status, then get the `location` header from the response and then set `window.location()` to that new redirected location URL.  Similarly, if you want something to happen with a 2xx response (such as show it to the user), then your Javascript that makes the ajax call has to insert that response in the page or put up an `alert()` or something similar.

Comment: See [How to properly redirect in nodejs ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078641/how-to-properly-redirect-in-nodejs-expressjs/41078774#41078774) for some more explanation.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks so much for the help. I redirected using the result of the ajax call but apparently then the middleware gets re-executed before rendering those pages. The middleware then expects an id-token from the client which isn't present when the page is redirected using the result of the ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that when you redirect, the client get the redirected URL and issues an entirely new http request.  That starts a completely new request cycle on your server that will go through all your middleware again that matches that new URL.

Automatic client redirects do NOT include custom headers from the original response.  If that's what you were expecting, that will not work.  If you're following a redirect manually from an Ajax call, you can manually get the token from the redirect response header and manually add it to a new Ajax call to the redirected location.

If you're expecting the browser or some automatic redirect to handle the redirect, they won't take the token with them from the headers.  So, your server will have to either send the response to the original URL without redirecting or you will have to put the token in something that will survive the redirect such as a query parameter on the redirect (usually a bad idea for a credential) or in a cookie or in a server-side session object that is tied to a cookie.

Comment: @HemantVashist - Does this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.