# How can I update my raw mongodb database using get method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update my database using the get method, the reason behind updating the DB using the get method is because when the get method will be called a value will be increased automatically.

This is my code where I am trying to update the database inside the get method. It's possible by mongoose but I am using raw MongoDB to update it. is it possible to update? or any other way to update it automatically when `/:shortUrl` will be requested into the server.

```
  app.get('/:shortUrl', async (req, res) => {
            const filter = {
                short: req.params.shortUrl
            }


            const updateDoc = {
                $inc: {
                    clicks: 1
                }
            }

            const urlDoc = await bicycleAffiliateLinksCollection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, updateDoc, {
                new: false,
                upsert: true
            })

            console.log(urlDoc.value.short)
            res.redirect(`${urlDoc.value.full}?ref=${req.params.shortUrl}`)
            res.send({
                shortLink: urlDoc.value.short
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`$inc` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) instead. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
app.get('/:shortUrl', async (req, res) => {
  const filter = {
    short: req.params.shortUrl
  }

  const updateDoc = {
    $inc: {
      clicks: 1
    }
  }

  const urlDoc = await bicycleAffiliateLinksCollection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, updateDoc, {
    new: true,
    upsert: true
  })

  console.log(urlDoc)

  res.send({
    shortLink: urlDoc.short
  })
})
```

`upsert` will create a new document if missing and `new` will return contents of the new document.

Comment: Thank you but I am getting an empty object

Comment: @Fathe can you share your updated code (edit your question)? And is the count being incremented?  Also you are referring to urlDoc right?

Comment: ok I think your code is working but how can I redirect the URL to the targeted page? if I use this `res.redirect(`${urlDoc.full}`)` it creates a new object in the database which is calling the undefined infinity.

Comment: @Fathe are you calling the API using Javascript or directly in browser? If JS then that won't work.. checkout [How to properly redirect in NodeJS/ExpressJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078641/how-to-properly-redirect-in-nodejs-expressjs) or post a new question with relevant details if it still is not working.

Comment: I have updated my code, now it working fine and redirecting to the actual page but I am getting an error on my cmd which is `(node:4740) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: @Fathe so both `.redirect()` and `send()` terminate the request so you can call only one..